# How do I group by on a dbref in MongoDB with Doctrine

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I want to do an aggregation query where I can group by a dbref. This is what I've tried.

```
$aggregation = array(
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => '$foreign.$id',
            'doc' => array(
                '$last' => '$$ROOT'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$sort' => array(
            'date' => -1
        )
    )
);

return $this->getDocumentManager()->getDocumentCollection('AppBundle:Collection')->aggregate($aggregation)->toArray();
```

But this attempt fails because you're not allowed to use the second `$` sign in `'$foreign.$id'`. How can I do this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching I've found this [Bug Ticket on the monogdb Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14466) which deals with basically this / an similar issue.

The [last comment](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14466?focusedCommentId=1598429&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-1598429) on this ticket offers an workaround to resolve the issue as an command line code. I've taken this solution and built it into an aggregation query which solved my problem.

```
$aggregation = array(
    array(
        '$addFields' => array(
            'foreignId' => array(
                '$arrayToObject' => array(
                    '$map' => array(
                        'input' => array(
                            '$objectToArray' => '$foreign'
                        ),
                        'in' => array(
                            'k' => array(
                                '$cond' => array(
                                    array(
                                        '$eq' => array(
                                            array(
                                                '$substrCP' => array(
                                                    '$$this.k', 0, 1
                                                )
                                            ),
                                            array(
                                                '$literal' => '$'
                                            )
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        '$substrCP' => array(
                                            '$$this.k',1,['$strLenCP' => '$$this.k']
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    '$$this.k'
                                )
                            ),
                            'v' => '$$this.v'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => '$foreignId',
            'doc' => array(
                '$last' => '$$ROOT'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$sort' => array(
            'date' => -1
        )
    )
);
$this->getDocumentManager()->getDocumentCollection('AppBundle:Collection')->aggregate($aggregation)->toArray();
```

This query gives me the correct and expected result.